# STM32H7 External Loader cannot access the external memory by ST link

Tags: c++, c, embedded

I am trying to load image file(hex format) in the external Nor flash memory deivce (QSPI connection).  When trying with ST Link, I could not able to access the memory location of external flash at address 0x90000000.  Boot code was generated successfully. My external loader is shown in the ST Link as below.

[image]
Error occured at the erase operation!!!

[image]

1. I checked with Chip write protection bit. It is disabled.
2. Sector Erase given, checked with the signal, the QSPI signals are not generated, no clock, no chip select, no data signals.
3. ST link says cannot access the address 0x90000000.
4. Tried with STM32 Cube Programmer too. same error remains.

[image]

Comment: Did you implement your own loader ? Or did you use an example provided by STMicro ? Same about the memory: is it a model directly supported by one of the example code ? There are plenty of parameters to setup for a QSPI Flash, it's easy to make a mistake.

Comment: From example, I made my own loader, with the QSPI pins, init, write and read SectorErase are implemented.  The model doesn't support the example code directly.

Comment: Did you debug this loader directly on the target ? (before using it from STM32CubeProgrammer)

Comment: No I didn't, Should I load and check for the QSPI signals, the code doesn't start with main, hence thought to load directly. didn't debug it. And my linker script is set to Load in RAM address.    RAM (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K

Comment: I don't want to be rude but you are really expecting this (not so obvious) software to work perfectly at first go ? Use a debugger and debug your software on the target. If it works fine, you can use it through another tool. If you don't manage to make it work, you can post more specific questions here :)

Comment: QSPI read, write, Erase are done successfully by another project, whereas boot code is not debug able all its functions are called by the tool (ST-link or STMCubeProgrammer)